# SPDY support with Dropwizard client

Tags: dropwizard, spdy

Dropwizard provides instrumented HTTP clients to integrate with other web apps. How to connect to a SPDY web service with Dropwizard client?

If SPDY is not supported by these clients, is there any other open-source, instrumented Dropwizard-compatible library which provides this.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily build a client using [Netflix Feign](https://github.com/Netflix/feign). Use the [OkHttp Client](https://github.com/Netflix/feign/tree/master/okhttp) to get SPDY support.